# Mounting file system in docker fails sometimes

Tags: docker

I'm trying to do something pretty trivial with Docker, and it seems to work sometimes, but not each time I try it. The command

```
docker run -v /Users/:/mnt/users/ ubuntu ls /mnt/users
```

works when I run it first time, but repeating it may give either

```
docker: Error response from daemon: mkdir /Users: file exists.
```

or sometimes

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Bad response from Docker engine.
```

response. Sorry if I'm missing something trivial, but I cannot imagine this is expected behaviour?

Running OS X 10.11.5 and docker version 1.12.0-rc3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try getting rid of the trailing slash at the end of the directory path, e.g.,

`docker run -v /Users:/mnt/users ubuntu ls /mnt/users`

I know Docker had some issues with that and may still cause problems.

Comment: I'm also not sure if using `/mnt` location for a Docker volume is kosher in all cases, but see if the trailing slash isn't the real culprit here.

Comment: Thanks, removing trailing slash seems to work! And I can avoid using /mnt folder inside docker, thanks for the hint.